# How to set audio input to internal mic when plugging headset?

Tags: audio

I have a headset, but it's mic is not of good quality and I want to use headset's headphones while using laptop's internal mic.
When I plug that headset, internal mic (as well as internal speakers) is automuted and there is no such an option in audio input parameters.

Comment: So internal mic disappears in input settings when you plug in your headset?

Comment: @EricG, yes. I would like to see both of options (internal and headset's mic)  in these settings.

Comment: Just have seen that it's the same for me...Strange

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for me is using pavucontrol. Install it via AppCenter or

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Start it and choose your internal mic. Try to mute your external and unmute your internal mic via the button in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: In the list of input devices I have "Internal mic (unplugged)". So when I choose it, the levels indicator still shows headset mic's signal.

Comment: I updated the answer, does that help?

Comment: No, it didn't. I did exactly what you wrote and still my headset mic's signal is active, not internal mic's. Is it working for you?
I remember on Windows there was a checkbox in Realtek HD Audio Manager, something like "Split audio devices when headset plugged". I need something like that here.